# Knockoutjs event binding not working

Tags: knockout.js

i was reading way out to attach mouse over and out with Knockoutjs and then i got a page http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/event-binding.html

from here i got a code for attaching mouse over and out with event binding in Knockoutjs. i try to paste the code in jsfiddle and try to run but nothing happen when i run the code. here is the jsfiddle link https://jsfiddle.net/tridip/6u4veobj/

### here is the mouse over and out code

```
<div>
    <div data-bind="event: { mouseover: enableDetails, mouseout: disableDetails }">
        Mouse over me
    </div>
    <div data-bind="visible: detailsEnabled">
        Details
    </div>
</div>

var viewModel = {
        detailsEnabled: ko.observable(false),
        enableDetails: function() {
            alert('over');
            this.detailsEnabled(true);
        },
        disableDetails: function() {
            alert('out');
            this.detailsEnabled(false);
        }
    };
    ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

i also try to run the below different code for mouseout and over and that also does not work. the code as follows

```
<ul data-bind="foreach: items">
    <li data-bind="text: name, event: { mouseover: toggle, mouseout: toggle }, css: { hover: selected }"></li>
</ul>

var Item = function(name) {
    this.name = ko.observable(name);
    this.selected = ko.observable(false);
    this.toggle = function() {
       this.selected(!this.selected());   
    }
};

var viewModel = {
    items: ko.observableArray([
        new Item("one"),
        new Item("two"),
        new Item("three")
    ])
};
ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

i just do not understand am i missing something. just help me to figure out what i missed for which mouse over and out code does not work. thanks

Comment: hey some one tell me what i am missing for which mouse over & out not working in jsfiddle.......?

Comment: Did you try checking it by writing the code in a html page and running it in browser to see if you get any exceptions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first step to take when debugging a problem like this is to open the browser's developer tools by pressing <kbd>F12</kbd> to check for errors.

Here are the errors I see in the debug tools console when I run your jsfiddle:

> Mixed Content: The page at
>   'https://fiddle.jshell.net/tridip/6u4veobj/show/' was loaded over
>   HTTPS, but requested an insecure script
>   'http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/2.2.1/knockout-min.js'.
>   This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.
>   (index):27 Uncaught ReferenceError: ko is not defined

So either update your Knockout cdnjs link to use `https`, or access your jsfiddle using `http` so that the page and the ko script download are using the same protocol:
http://jsfiddle.net/tridip/6u4veobj/

Comment: thanks man for nice help.....i could think that knockout.js file link was problem.